# I don't understand what the distance is that they are asking

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polar-coordinates

I don't understand what this problem is asking for, any help would be appreciated:
"Consider the spiral r = θ and a ray—emanating from the pole—that intersects the spiral. What is the distance between any two consecutive points of intersection?
"

Comment: $r=\theta$ means that the point that is $r$ away from the origin makes an angle $\theta$ in the plane.

Comment: I know the graph $r=\theta$ but I don't understand what the distance is that they are asking

Comment: @Pagaley12 `I don't understand what the distance is that they are asking` Does a ray from the origin intersect the spiral? Multiple times? Then the question is likely asking about the distance between two such consecutive intersections.

Comment: I think they were asking for me to draw a straight line from the origin at any angle and see the distance between two points that it intersects on the spiral

Comment: @Pagaley12 Right. The spiral is $\,r = \theta\,$, think at the equation of a ray now.

Comment: Does $r=-1$ and other negatives count? it would change the answer

Comment: Does $\theta\in [0,+\infty)$?

Comment: @JasonKim Everything I know is what I posted, I submitted the assignment with 2$\pi$ as my answer and it was correct so I'm not sure

Comment: Then $r$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Why is $(0,0)$ not a point of intersection? If $\theta=0$ then $r=0$ so $(0,0)$ belongs to spiral (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer but I think the problem is to find the Distance $AB$ in the figure. Choose the line (Red) suitably.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The spiral $r=\theta$ looks like this:

[image]

Note: Green is based off of $r$ is negative (which is seen as not counted).

Since $\theta$ repeats every $2\pi,$ (well, it doesn't actually repeat, but $\sin$ and $\cos$ values are both the same value if $2\pi$ gets added) the answer is $2\pi.$

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ a point of intersection? If not, why?

Comment: I don't quite understand this notation, so I can't explain.

Comment: Is the point of the plane $(0,0)$ (the origin) a point of intersection between the blue segment and the spiral? (Sorry, English is not my native language.)

Comment: :P I meant the problem notation

Comment: Ah, ok. :) The question is not precise enough. I mean, if $\theta\in [0,+\infty)$ then one of two consecutive points must be $(0,0)$, hence the distance between them is $\theta$  for all $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ (by definition). If $\theta\in (0,+\infty)$ then your solution is perfect.